# Create a new array which have non matching values of two arrays without using any native function of PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
$array1 = array('A','T','L','H','K','L');
$array2 = array('T','L');
```

and I want a new array like

```
$array3 = array('A','H','K');
```

without using any inbuilt PHP function.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What's wrong with just initializing the new array as you did there?

Comment: This is not place to solve your test problems. If you want to learn something you have to achieve results yourself.

Comment: `without using any inbuilt PHP function.`.... so it's homework. Then have a stab at doing it yourself first, otherwise you'll never justify any grade that your homework scores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using array function.

```
    function uniqueArray($array1,$array2) {
        $result = array();
        foreach($array1 as $val1) { //Array1 - Array2
            $flag = 0;
            foreach($array2 as $val2) {
              if($val1 == $val2){
                  $flag = 1;
                  break;
              }
            }
            if($flag == 0) {
                $result[] = $val1;
            }
        }
        foreach($array2 as $val1) { //Array2 - Array1
            $flag = 0;
            foreach($array1 as $val2) {
              if($val1 == $val2){
                  $flag = 1;
                  break;
              }
            }
            if($flag == 0) {
                $result[] = $val1;
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First merge the two arrays to loop over all of the items.

Then loop over the merged array and add the item to the results array if it isn't contained by both of the original arrays.

```
function get_all_items_not_shared_by_both_arrays($array1, $array2) {
    $merged_array = array_merge($array1,$array2);
    $result_array = array();
    foreach ($merged_array as $item) {
        if ( !(in_array($item,$array1) && in_array($item,$array2)) ) {
            $result_array[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $result_array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any predefined array functions:

```
$array1 = array('A','T','L','H','K','L');
$array2 = array('T','L');
$array3=array();

foreach($array1 as $val1) {
   $isExists=false;
   foreach($array2 as $val2) {
       if($val2 == $val1){
          $isExists=true;
          break;
       }      
   }
   if(!$isExists)
     $array3[]=$val1;   
}

print_r($array3);
```

**Explanation:**

Searching array 1 element is not exists in array2, then adding element to array3, and repeating the process for last element of an array.